# How To Trigger Event in PHP At A time Decided by the website's user

Tags: php, html, apache, datetime, raspberry-pi

I Have A server set up that whenever an HTTP link is visited the lights in my house go on and off.
I want to make a website that lets you schedule when this happens.
I'm running this website on a Raspberry Pi with Apache.
My question is how can I program the raspberry pi that it gets information on what time to visit the HTTP link and turn on the lights from the website
I Do not Know if this is done on the website through PHP or on the server through python or something else
Any Help Would Be Greatly Appreciated.
This Is The Code So Far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> </head> 
 <body style="text-align:center;"> 
    <?php   
        if(isset($_POST['button2'])) { 
            $command = escapeshellcmd('wget http://192.168.1.128:49949/Test1');
        $output = shell_exec($command);
        echo $output;
        } 
    ?> 
    
    <form method="post"> 
<input type="submit" name="button2"
                value="Toggle"/> 
    </form> 
</head> 
</html>
```

Comment: Do you want to run it once or schedule it?

Comment: Also, how do the user specify time to run the event?

Comment: I want to chose that time in the website say the user input 12Am daily and the server to send the http request at 12am every day

Comment: This is a problem a bit too complicated to be a single question in SO. PHP doesn't have a long running process for running scheduled job. You need to combine [cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) with [some scheduler library](https://packagist.org/packages/peppeocchi/php-cron-scheduler) to run anything regularly.

Comment: And before that, you need some way to store the job that is submitted. I believe its best to use database for persistent storage (e.g. [SQLite through PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php), [MariaDB / MySQL through PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php). Or you'd have to implement your own storage format with [fwrite](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) and [fread](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bit too complicated for a single SO question. I'd break down into 3 parts to answer:

### How to receive and store user's schedule?

You first need an HTML form that user can specify the time for the command to run. The tricky part is to store the scheduled job somehow. PHP do not have a long running process for job scheduling. You need some per persistent storage.

For example,

1. [SQLite through PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php)
2. [MariaDB / MySQL through PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php).
3. Using CSV through [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) and [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php)
4. Implement your own storage format with [fwrite](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php) and [fread](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php).

### How to run the scheduled job?

As stated before PHP doesn't have a long running process for running scheduled job. Linux system have [cron](https://opensource.com/article/17/11/how-use-cron-linux) to run things regularly. You can schedule it to regularly run a PHP script. Then in the PHP script, you can implement logic to actually run the stored schedule job.

You may use [some scheduler library](https://packagist.org/packages/peppeocchi/php-cron-scheduler) to help you with it.